# Плавное исчезновение текста при scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

при скролле в низ текст начинает исчезать

Пример Сайт))

http://kenarai.github.io/#/about

Заранее Очень благодарю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант мы можем просто уменьшать прозрачность текста.
Подробней о [`.scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();              // Текущая позиция  скрола
  $(".text").css("opacity", (150 - height) / 100); // Так как нужно указывать прозрачность вроде .50 и т.д., то делим на 100
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 250vh;
}

.text {
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 190px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  My name is Ken Arai and I am a product designer
</div>
```

Comment: да - если заглянуть внутрь того сайта, то эффект реализован через прозрачность.